# Sort rich text columns in sharepoint online 2016

Tags: html, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list with a few rich text columns but in the view, the headlines of these don't have the button to sort or filter them as all other non rich text columns have. Is there a way to enable such features for rich text?

Answer (score 0):

It's by design that rich text fields cannot be sorted.

You could refer to this post:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92920/sort-and-filter-rich-text

> The reason why they are disabled is because the rich text fields
>   contains html formatting, and will by default always be wrapped inside
>   two hidden div tags and making the functions useless.